# Get Inserted Records with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The below snippet demonstrates a super simple Flask app that inserts records in the `Account` table if there is no conflict (using the `on_conflict_do_nothing` method).

I would like to return the inserted records as a JSON object in the response.

Is there a "built in" way to return the records? I know I can get the inserted primary key IDs, but I'm after the entire record set.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = <postgres>
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Account(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    transaction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True,)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    stmt = (
        insert(Account)
        .values(request.json)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[Account.transaction_id])
    )
    db.session.execute(stmt)
    db.session.commit()

    result = None  # return inserted records

    return jsonify({
        'status': 'success',
        'result': result
    })
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#insert-returning

Answer (score 2):

I used `returning` as pointed out by @snakecharmerb in the comment.

```
def insert():
    stmt = (
        insert(Account)
        .values(request.json)
        .returning(Account.__table__)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[Account.transaction_id])
    )
    result_proxy = db.session.execute(stmt)
    db.session.commit()

    result = [dict(row) for row in result_proxy]

    return jsonify({
        'status': 'success',
        'result': result
    })
```